# Only trigger a rule after some point in time

Tags: prometheus

Let's say there is a point in time `1606780800` (`2020-12-01T00:00:00Z`).

And I want to implement a rule that only triggers right after that point in time.

Intuitively I'd implement it like

```
some_vector > 1234 AND time() > 1606780800
```

It does not parse though: `parse error: comparisons between scalars must use BOOL modifier`

If I add `bool` the other parsing error appears: `parse error: set operator "and" not allowed in binary scalar expression`

So, is it possible to implement a self-contained rule (as it had everything there and I didn't need to create extra recording rules, mostly because I will need to have more than one such rule) that implements just that: a regular vector condition followed by a scalar time condition?

There is some *relevant* discussion, but not quite it: https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
some_vector > 1234 and ON() vector(time()) > 1606780800
```

You need to convert one of the scalars to vector so you can filter, and then ensure the `and` applies to everything by providing an empty `on`.

Comment: Awesome! I tried it similarly but without `ON()`. Still not sure I fully understand what `ON()` here _exactly_ means. But at least now I can make a thoughtful research, thanks!